# How can I make persistent changes from Pyhon's side to objects stored in std::vector's as std::shared_ptr's

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Imagine I define two classes (`Foo` and `Bar`). `Bar` stores two `Foo`s in a `std::vector` as `std::shared_ptr`s. I want to expose everything to Python by using `pybind11`. In addition, I want `Foo` to also support dynamic attributes, which requires using `pybind11::dynamic_attr()` during the binding stage. Everything works fine as long as I don't try to add dynamic attributes to `Foo` instances only through the vector that stores them.
Since it is not easy to explain my issue in words, here is a MWE:

The `pybind11` module is defined in the `pyissue.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

namespace py = pybind11;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        a = 5;
    }

    ~Foo() {

    }

    int a;
};

class Bar {
public:
    Bar() {
        foos.push_back(std::make_shared<Foo>());
        foos.push_back(std::make_shared<Foo>());
    }
    ~Bar() {

    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> foos;
};


PYBIND11_MODULE(pybug, m) {
    py::class_<Foo, std::shared_ptr<Foo>> foo(m, "Foo", py::dynamic_attr());
    foo
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("a", &Foo::a);

    py::class_<Bar> bar(m, "Bar");
    bar
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("foos", &Bar::foos);
```

which can be compiled as follows (at least on my Linux box):

```sh
g++ pyissue.cpp -shared --std=c++11 -fPIC `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` -o pyissue`python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

Now the following python snippet works exactly as intended:

```py
import pyissue

bar = pyissue.Bar()
print(bar.foos[0].a) # prints 5

bar.foos[0].a = 2
print(bar.foos[0].a) # prints 2

myfoo = bar.foos[0]
myfoo.b = 3 # this is a dynamic attribute, it exists only on python's side
print(myfoo.b) # prints 3
```

However, the next snippet raises an `AttributeError: 'pybug.Foo' object has no attribute 'b'` exception:

```py
import pyissue

bar = pyissue.Bar()

bar.foos[0].b = 2
print(b.foos[0].b) # here comes the exception
```

My question boils down to: is there any way to make the last snippet work?

**Edit**: note that if I explicitly keep a reference to an object, then I can use it without any issues. For instance the following code will work as intended:

```py
import pyissue

bar = pyissue.Bar()

myfoo = bar.foos[0]
bar.foos[0].b = 2
print(b.foos[0].b) # prints 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer with bare citations from pybind11 doc since it's quite well explained there.

> The major downside of these implicit conversions is that containers must be converted (i.e. copied) on every Python->C++ and C++->Python transition, which can have implications on the program semantics and performance. Please read the next sections for more details and alternative approaches that avoid this.

link: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#stl-containers

> By default, classes exported from C++ do not support this and the only writable attributes are the ones explicitly defined using class_::def_readwrite() or class_::def_property().

link: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#dynamic-attributes

**Edit:**

`bar.foos` returns a **copy** of the `std::vector` and it's internals. If you don't store returned python objects, you'll get brand-new python objects at each call.

Yes, python `Foo` wrappers  hold the references (plural!) to the original C++ instance. But dynamic attributes are properties of python wrappers, therefore different python wrappers with same referent does not share dynamic attributes.

**Edit 2:**

Your latter snippet is a bit puzzling. I guess that some caching on pybind11/cython side might be involved.

*Update:*
Answering the title of the question:

> How can I make persistent changes from Pyhon's side to objects stored in std::vector's as std::shared_ptr's

Make changes to C++ instance, not to a python wrapper around it.

Comment: I feel like this answer is not really helpful since, as far as I understand, the vector stores pointers and hence copying it to and from Python should not prevent me from changing the contents of the *pointed* objects. Moreover, note that I use `py::dynamic_attr()` (and hence the second snippet is not pertaining)

Comment: I have added one more example to show the "quirkiness" of the issue

Comment: @lr1985 Updated the answer. Hope now it's more helpful.

Comment: @Sergei so is there a way to access dynamically added attributes from function in fileA.py when calling another function with a reference to the same object in fileB.py? In other words, do the dynamic attributes exist only inside the single python scope they were created in? Can I access them back in the C++ somehow?